# How is a transaction's output signed?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, signature

In a transaction `Tx`, the hash pointer of the earlier transaction (say `TxE`) that serves as input to `Tx` must be signed by the sender `S` of `Tx`. This is to show that `S` was the recipient of `TxE`.
It remains to show that `S` agrees with the output of `Tx`. At which stage does `S` sign the output of `Tx`? 
I assume (s)he does so. Else, what would prevent an attacker from looking at `Tx` just after `S` broadcasted it, and modify the output (so that he is the recipient) before rebroadcast?

In other words:
**The scriptSig proves the sender owns the input of Tx. What proves that the sender approves the output of the Tx?**

rgds

P.S: the transaction I am considering atm is:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature also signs the Pubkey Script and Amount (which together would represent what you reference as "output of `Tx`").

Quoting the [Transaction section of the Developer's guide](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#transactions):

> Bob’s secp256k1 signature doesn’t just prove Bob controls his private
> key; it also makes the non-signature-script parts of his transaction
> tamper-proof so Bob can safely broadcast them over the peer-to-peer
> network.

[image]
<sub>Image Source: [Developer Guide: Transactions](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#transactions)</sub>

> As illustrated in the figure above, the data Bob signs includes the
> txid and output index of the previous transaction, the previous
> output’s pubkey script, the pubkey script Bob creates which will let
> the next recipient spend this transaction’s output, and the amount of
> satoshis to spend to the next recipient. In essence, the entire
> transaction is signed except for any signature scripts, which hold the
> full public keys and secp256k1 signatures.

Comment: I would note this is true for SIGHASH_ALL, but not the others.

Comment: Thank you very much; but I am not sure I fully understand. Indeed, I saw this picture before but I am not sure what its message is. Would someone be so kind as to explain it once more plz?

Comment: @Murch Considering the picture I originally posted, do you mean that each of the scriptSig in Tx not only certifies the ownership of TxE's outputs, but also confirms Tx' s output?

Comment: Yes, typically every input contains signatures that cover both the outputs of the previous transaction being spent, AND the outputs where the transaction containing the signatures sends them to.

Comment: I  other words: it is not just signing to prove ownership, but it proves agreement with the transaction.

Comment: @Pieter Wuille. Thanks for this explanation. Apologies for being a nit-picky but: which signature covers what? Or is it that a same signature covers outputs and inputs?

Comment: Every signature covers both inputs and outputs. The diagram and the linked Developer Guide explain that in much more detail than I can put in a comment.

Comment: The figure does not make sense because it suggests that the signed data covers everything from left to right including the private key. Furthermore the link needs to be updated.